FlatList's vertical scrollbar visible despite showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
In my functional component below, FlatList's vertical scrollbar remains visible despite showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
 const Section = () => {
    ...
    return data && <SafeAreaView 
                ...
            <FlatList
            ...
            data={data}
            horizontal={false}
            scrollEnabled = {true}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            ...
            />

The FlatList is not wrapped in a ScrollView.
The (top-down) component hierarchy is as follows:
...
Suspense
Section
Anonymous
View
FlatList <----- FlatList in question
ForwardRef
VirtualizedList
View
VirtualizedListContextprovider
VirtualizedListContext.provider 
ScrollView
ScrollView
...

react-native version: 0.74.5
Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

16/11/2024 Update:
Apparently, the issue was caused by debug={true}

it seems that your FlatList is indeed nested within a ScrollView. When a FlatList is wrapped inside a ScrollView, the parent ScrollView’s scrollbar may still show.
Steps to try to fix this

Remove the ScrollView Wrapper, If the ScrollView wrapping the FlatList is not essential
Use nestedScrollEnabled={true} this would allow the flatlist to handle the scrolling, hereby allowing showsVerticalScrollIndicator to be active


Thank you for your insight.

Just wanted to reiterate that the FlatList is not wrapped in a ScrollView.
The component hierarchy, posted in my original message, is top-down and not bottom-up, which means the ScrollView, you see there, is not a parent of the FlatList instead it is inherited from VirtualizedList, the FlatList is based on.
Adding nestedScrollEnabled={true} didn't help

